# Request to not to delete the responses

Tags: discussion

As I observed, many users are posting some comments and when they get a reply (*which either helps them or not*), after some time they are deleting their comment. Even this is happening with posting Meta question, which I saw recently. I don't want to name anyone.

Here are some actions, as I observed:

- Deleting the meta questions
- Deleting the main question if someone raises concern that it might be off-topic.
- Deleting comments after somedays
- Limiting community participation to just upvoting or downvoting the posts & comments.

For such users, I suggest the following things:

- **Don't think you will be criticized for being wrong.** If someone does criticized you or being sarcastic with you, just flag their response and move on. Also, don't take downvotes as negative.
- **Don't think that only having high rep users can respond better**: Even you can respond better. If you have a point, present it / debate on it. We are a community, we can't move forward if you don't share your thoughts.
- **Don't think you are lesser in any means comparing with high rep users**: Don't take anyone's explanation for granted just so that they have a high reputation. Try to understand it, if it is out of your understanding, try to discuss it on meta or in the main chatroom.

Please feel free to share your thoughts/reasons if I am getting it wrong in any way.

We all are equal here and would love to hear from each and every one of you. Hope this encourages you to come forward. If anyone still likes to be anonymous or wants to have limited participation, it is all good.